# Toggle Class of Child Element when Selecting Accordion Tab

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ajax

I am struggling to come up with a method of toggling the css class of a  tag that sits within my Ajax Accordion header.

I would like the class of the span tag, within the header, to change depending of whether the particular header is selected or not (basically changing a plus icon to a minus icon). Code for the Accordion Section is below. I have yet to try and create and JS or Jquery Script.

```
<asp:Accordion 
    ID="Accordion1"   
    CssClass="accordion"  
    HeaderCssClass="acc_Header"  
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="acc_HeaderSelected"  
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
    AutoSize ="none"
    RequireOpenedPane="false"
    FadeTransitions ="true"
    TransitionDureation="250"
    FramesPerSecond="40"
    SelectedIndex="-1"
    SuppressHeaderPostBack ="true"
    runat="server">
        <Panes>
            <asp:AccordionPane ID="SubsidencePane1" runat="server">
                <Header><span class="icon-plus-circle"></span>What is the definition of subsidence?</Header>
                <Content>
                    <p>This is where the ground beneath a structure has suffered downward movement, causing damage to the property.</p>  
                    <p>The movement of the ground is a consequence of some activity in the ground unconnected with the weight or presence of the building.</p>
                    <p>The damage that normally occurs in properties suffering from subsidence is cracking in the walls; these cracks can be diagonally, vertical or horizontal.</p>  
                    <p>However not all cracking is attributable to subsidence therefore a specialist surveyor is often called upon to determine the cause of the cracking to ensure the cause falls under the definition of subsidence.</p>
                </Content>
            </asp:AccordionPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".accordion div").click(function () {
            $("> span", this).toggleClass("icon-plus-circle icon-minus-circle");
        });
```